# How can I highlight minimum values in a levelplot in R?

Tags: r, levelplot

How can I highlight the ten minimum value grid points of a 385*373 levelplot as black points?
I have the indexes as well as the coordinates of the ten minimum grid points. Preferably I would use the idexes...

I have the following levelplot displaying Europe's air temperature (Z), with X and Y being longitude and latitude respectively.

```
levelplot(Z ~ X*Y, data=data  , xlab="X" , col.regions = heat.colors(100))
```

One further question: how can I add the country contours with the same projection type as the base data? I tried that before within another function

```
image(x,y,data,...)  
data(wrdl_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = TRUE)
```

where the country contours plot seemed to have a totally different projection. However, I want to do this for `levelplot()` now.
I am very thankful for any help!

Comment: Answered your main question below. Concerning your second problem I would suggest to open another question and add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

`lattice` plots differ to base plots. Therefore using `points` does not work. But there are replacement functions. Here is a way to do it:

```
x    <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 100)
y    <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 100)
z    <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- cbind(expand.grid(x=x, y=y), z)

minimum <- grid[which.min(grid$z),]

levelplot(z ~ x * y, grid, panel = function(...) {
            panel.levelplot(...)
            panel.points(x = minimum$x, y = minimum$y, pch = "x", cex  =2)
          })
```

We are basically building up the plot inside the `panel` argument.

[image]